# How to read two input values in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a bash script which takes multiple user inputs. Before the script will take any action, I want to ensure that all values have been added by a user.

```
  #/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter the domain Name: " domain
read -p "Please Enter path where you want to save your result: " path
if [[ -z "$domain" && "$path"]]; then
    echo "You have not entered the Domain Name"
    exit 1

else
    echo "Do Something Here"
fi
```

I have checked with 1 user input, working fine, but when trying with 2 user inputs, I am getting an error.

```
./test.sh: line 5: unexpected token `;', conditional binary operator expected
./test.sh: line 5: syntax error near `;'
./test.sh: line 5: `if [[ -z "$domain" && "$path"]]; then'
```

Thanks!

Comment: ```if [[ -z "$domain" && "$path"]]; then``` is invalid syntax ... it should be ```if [[ -z "$domain" ]] && [[ -z "$path" ]]; then```

Comment: @BookOfZeus how do I ensure that both values are entered because when I am entering one value and other is not even then my script is not giving me a message that I have not entered the second variable.

Comment: always make sure you have a space right before the ending conditional too, ```"$path"]];``` should be ```"$path" ]];```

Comment: sorry my bad, it should be ```||``` (or) not ```&&```

Comment: This code and its vague error message forces the errant user to wonder which of two conditions, (or maybe both), went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using the `[[` [double brackets](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS), you can use `||` to test if either of your conditions is true. In this case, your code would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read -p "Please enter the domain Name: " domain
read -p "Please Enter path where you want to save your result: " path
if [[ -z "$domain" || -z "$path" ]]; then
    echo "Either you have not entered the Domain Name, or you have not entered the path."
    exit 1
else
    echo "Do Something Here"
fi
```

Note that spaces around the brackets are necessary.
As others have pointed out, errors should be specific, so you should consider something like this:

```
if [[ -z "$domain" ]]; then
    echo "You have not entered the Domain Name"
    exit 1
elif [[ -z "$path" ]]; then
    echo "You have not entered the path"
    exit 1
fi
echo "Do something here"
```

It's a bit more verbose but gives the user more specific feedback.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting syntax error because you forgot to put a space between `"$path"` and `]` (bash uses spaces as delimiters).

If you want to fail when at least one condition is wrong, you should use the `||` (OR) operator.

```
#/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter the domain name: " domain
read -p "Please enter the path where you want to save your result: " path
if [[ -z "$domain" ]] || [[ -z "$path" ]] ; then
    echo "You didn't enter the domain name or the save path"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Do something here"
fi
```

Comment: Errors should be specific.  (Prompting the user to guess *which* item went wrong wastes their time.)